# How do I restore my notes on macOS Sierra?

Tags: backup, macos, restore, notes.app

As mentioned in the title, I need to restore my notes from files I previously copied manually from:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes
```

I know that may sound stupid, but I was on a hurry to update my macOS, and I just thought I could copy the files manually and restore them back later.
Now even when I copy the files back to their original location and reopen Notes app nothing shows up.

EDIT:

If anyone knows about a way to display my notes (Terminal command, open source tools or scripts...) from those backed-up files that would help, I do not mind copying everything manually.

Answer (score 2):

A very quick grab of all of the note body fields from the database:

`sqlite3 ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/NotesV6.storedata "select ZHTMLSTRING from ZNOTEBODY" > ~/Desktop/notes.html`

There is more organization in the database, but this will give you all of the text itself. The titles are listed separately in the database but should also be at the top of every note body, so this should be enough for reconstruction hopefully!

Edits:

Replace the `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/NotesV6.storedata` with the location of your NotesV6.storedata file ;)

Also depending on the version of OS X/macOS Notes that made the file, it may be `NotesVN.storedata` for a different `N`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i have used up all my tricks...i think the manual copy screwed up everything. Never trust sketchy youtube tutorials :) lesson learned